# Firebase Cloud Firestore Get Data with Custom Objects

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**About data types supported by cloud firestore...**

trying to get data using the following custom object:

```
public class Message implements IMessage {

private String id;
private String text;
private Author author;
private Date createdAt;

public Message() {}

public Message(String id, String text, Author author, Date createdAt) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.author = author;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

@Override
public Author getUser() {
    return author;
}

@Override
public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public static class Author implements IUser {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String avatar;

    public Author(String id, String name, String avatar) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }
  }
}
```

The following error occurred "**Found conflicting getters for name getUser**"
The question is **does firestore supports nested objects?**
or the error is caused by me being totally idiot!!
if it's very stupid question please ignore it...

Comment: Please provide the a [mcv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how you are using the `getUser()` method.